# Can't open Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app, install

I install the Salesforce1 and can open the application. I have Samsung G SIII and 4.3 Version.

Just appears Blue screen with salesforce1. In another device I can sign in.

Can help me?

Comment: It is very hard to say what may be issue. Have you tried to login from web browser and if thats working ?

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall and then reinstalling it? Even though it was a fresh install, it might work to redo it.

Comment: Hello Jenny B, I try uninstall and reinstalling and don't work.